# Trying to find out why I lost my file system on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux

I recently made the following (i believe important) changes to my system

Actually I was following [this](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/lxc-linux-containers/) tutorial to use something called Linux Containers.

So can you tell me if any of the following stuff is capable enough to crash my system ?

**1.** Making changes to `/etc/fstab` or

**2.** `mount /cgroup` which will try to mount cgroups automatically or

**3** making changes to `etc/network/interfaces` or

**4** making changes to `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typo in fstab can definitely make a system un-bootable.  However, you should be able to boot from CD, mount the HD, and fix it.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the steps that i should take once i have booted from the CD ?

Comment: You'll need to mount the slice containing /etc onto a valid mount point.  Make sure to do it as read+write (as read-only is the default).  Then, you can use whatever editor you may have on the CD to edit the file.  Exact steps depend on distro/installation, and I'm unfamiliar with how Ubuntu does things by default.